# Consulta SQL en access a través de una variable string, utilizando comodines (*) para concatenar

Tags: sql, ms-access, like, where

muy buenas a todos.

Estoy empezando a utilizar SQL en access pero me he encontrado con un problema al concatenar los astericsos para filtrar un string determinado. Ahora estoy utilizando un número pero posteriormente utilizaré un TextBox como campo de busqueda.

```
Private Sub Comando2_Click()
On Error GoTo errorExit

Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT * FROM ConsultaFormAmonestacionesFiltrados"
    
    ''Busca los que empiezan por 22
    SQL = SQL & " WHERE id_Matricula LIKE " & "22" & "*"
    
    Me.TextoSalidaSQL = SQL
    Me.AASubFormPruebas.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    
errorExit:

End Sub
```

He probado a hacerlo directamente creando una consulta a mano y funciona perfectamente pero cuando trato de crearla desde código VBA deja de funcionar. He capturado las distintas pruebas que muestro a continuación.

[image: Prueba desde el editor SQL integrado en access]

Como se puede ver la consulta me muestra perfectamente todos los registros que empiezan por 23.
Ahora mostraré el código VBA sobre un formulario.

[image: Tras pulsar el botón se obtiene el resultado esperado.]

No se han utilizado comodines y el string SQL se limita a buscar los registros id_Matricula = 232.
Esto funciona perfectamente pero cuando quiero hacer busquedas limitadas o con ciertos criterios, el código no me funciona.

Aquí muestro el còdigo que no me funciona.
[image: Código con criterio de busqueda. id_Matricula debe empezar por 22]

He probado muchas combinaciones. Comillas dobles, simples, %, [*], [%], etc. pero no he consegido nada al respecto. Estoy un poco desesperado.

Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.
Un saludo.

Comment: Prueba con esto: `SQL = SQL & " WHERE id_Matricula LIKE '" & "22" + "*'"`. Es decir comillas simples ante del 22 y después del asterisco

Comment: ¡¡¡Sí señor!!! Mis más sinceros agradecimientos. No te puedes hacer idea de las combinaciones que he probado. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Muy buenas. Aunque llevo tiempo por aquí sigo sin entender algunas cosas. ¿Podría alguien explicarme que significa "Cerrada. Esta pregunta esta fuera de tema"?. No sé cual es el motivo y me desconcierta ya que es muy posible que vuelva a cometer el mismo error.